# Category and Sub Category in single Dropdownlistfor - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to list the Categories as in the picture:

[image]

Now I could only list all the categories using VievComponent.

I have a model class like this

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

ViewComponent Class

```
public class CategoryListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public CategoryListViewComponent(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View(new CategoryListModel()
        {
            SelectedCategory = RouteData.Values["category"]?.ToString(),
            Categories = _categoryService.GetAll()
        });
    }
```

ViewComponent File

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
{
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-submenu" data-menu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CategoryList" asp-route-category="@item.Name.ToLower()" class="menu-link @(Model.SelectedCategory==item.Name.ToLower()?"active":"")">
            <span class="menu-text">@item.Name</span>
            <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

And controller

```
public IActionResult CategoryList()
{
    return View(new CategoryListModel()
    {
        Categories = _categoryService.GetAll()
    });
}
```

This way I can to list all my Categories, but how can I list the main and sub categories as in the picture?

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTHdM.png)

Comment: Could you show us the current result with the above codes?

Comment: sure, I added it to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have another model for the subcategory items, something like this:

**Model:**

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubCategoryModel> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryListModel
{
    public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewComponent Page:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-submenu" data-menu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true">
            <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CategoryList" asp-route-category="@item.Name.ToLower()" class="menu-link @(Model.SelectedCategory==item.Name.ToLower()?"active":"")">
                <span class="menu-text">@item.Name</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        @if (item.SubCategories != null && item.SubCategories.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var subitem in item.SubCategories)
            {
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-submenu" data-menu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true">
                    <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CategoryList" asp-route-category="@subitem.Name.ToLower()" class="menu-link">
                        <span class="menu-text">@item.Name > @subitem.Name</span>
                        <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
</ul>
```

**ViewComponent Class:**

```
public class CategoryListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public CategoryListViewComponent(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View(new CategoryListModel()
        {
            Categories = _categoryService.GetAll()
        });
    }
}
```

**CategoryService:**

```
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    public List<CategoryModel> GetAll()
    {
        var categories = new List<CategoryModel>
        {
            new CategoryModel{ Id = 1, Name = "AA", SubCategories = new List<SubCategoryModel>
                {
                    new SubCategoryModel{ Id = 1, Name = "A1"},
                    new SubCategoryModel{ Id = 2, Name = "A2"},
                } 
            },
            new CategoryModel{ Id = 2, Name = "BB" , SubCategories = new List<SubCategoryModel>
                {
                    new SubCategoryModel{ Id = 1, Name = "B1"},
                    new SubCategoryModel{ Id = 2, Name = "B2"},
                } 
            },
            new CategoryModel{ Id = 3, Name = "CC"},
            new CategoryModel{ Id = 4, Name = "DD"},
        };
        return categories;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**UPdate:**

```
public List<CategoryModel> GetAll()
{
    var categories = new List<CategoryModel>
    {
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 1, Name = "AA"},
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 2, Name = "BB"},
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 3, Name = "CC", ParentId = 1},
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 4, Name = "DD", ParentId = 1},
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 5, Name = "EE", ParentId = 2},
        new CategoryModel{ Id = 6, Name = "FF", ParentId = 2},
    };

    return categories;
}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        @if (item.ParentId == null)
        {
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-submenu" data-menu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CategoryList" asp-route-category="@item.Name.ToLower()" class="menu-link @(Model.SelectedCategory==item.Name.ToLower()?"active":"")">
                    <span class="menu-text">@item.Name</span>
                    <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

        foreach (var subitem in Model.Categories.Where(s => s.ParentId == item.Id))
        {
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-submenu" data-menu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CategoryList" asp-route-category="@subitem.Name.ToLower()" class="menu-link">
                    <span class="menu-text">@item.Name > @subitem.Name</span>
                    <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        }

    }
</ul>
```

Comment: it worked thanks, so is there a way to do this without the subcategory table?

Comment: Yeah, you can set the `ParentId`, then it will repersent a subcategory, see my update.